# Reversible equation in Chemical Kinetics — Should I use definite integral when solving the differential equation?

Tags: kinetics, concentration

**I found this problem:**

We have the following reversible reaction: $A \ce{<=>[\ce{k_1}][\ce{k_2}]} B $, described by the kinetics equation:
$$\frac{d[X]}{dt} = k_1([A]_0-[X])-k_2([B]_0+[X])$$

**Where**
$[X]$ is the increase of molar concentration;
$[A]_0$ and $[B]_0$ are the initial concentrations of $A$ and $B$.

**Find** $[X]$ as a time dependent funcion.

---

**What I've tried:**

The differential equation above is the same as:

$$\frac{d[X]}{k_1[A]_0-k_2[B]_0 - (k_1+k_2)[X]} = dt$$

**Now, we should integrate both parts.**

---

**My questions are:**

1. Should I use the definite integral? Why? Am I right when I state that the equation becomes this?
   $$\int_{[X]_0}^{[X]} \frac{d[X]}{k_1[A]_0-k_2[B]_0 - (k_1+k_2)[X]} = \int_{t_0}^{t} dt$$
2. If $[X]$ is the "increase" of molar concentration, then is $[X]_0 = 0$?
3. Is $t_0 = 0$?

Thank you!

If I am wrong, please tell me the corect way of solving this. Thank you so much!

Comment: (1) Yes, why wouldn't you? You do this for a regular integrated rate law as well.

Comment: (2) Probably, but that depends on the statement of the problem. My reading is yes. (3) That also depends on the statement of the problem. My reading is yes.

Comment: Also, do not integrate to a bound on your integral that is the same as the variable of integration. That is, do not write $\int_{a}^{x}dx$. Use a dummy variable: $\int_{a}^{x}dx'$